# Make Mathematica show function template's arguments in different lines (i.e. in column) by default?

Tags: functions, formatting

I feel a bit uncomfortable with Mathematica 10's layout. I mean, I'm impressed how powerful functional programming can be and so on, but it's me or those programs are often just a bunch of nested functions with no way to make out which is the argument to whom?

So, is there a way to split every function prototype in a column - with correct indentation - by DEFAULT?

So to get, for example:

[indented http://imageshack.com/a/img539/5096/dc2bbe.gif](http://imageshack.com/a/img539/5096/dc2bbe.gif)

instead of this:

[not indented http://imageshack.com/a/img742/6458/5cf4bf.gif](http://imageshack.com/a/img742/6458/5cf4bf.gif)

That'd make everything easier - for me, at least.

You may think I'm another of those "traditional coders" who can't stand the change, and yes, a sort of... But who cares?

Any help, guys?